# Build id from the url path for caching

Tags: php, mysql, performance, algorithm, caching

I wanted to cache our data on database or maybe on a filesystem. but im not sure how to create id from different url's.

url path: daily / time / daylight / method / location .json  = "/daily/12-02-20/yes/5/london.json"

each value can be different and if one of the value is different, then i want to save new cache with new data.

any suggestion on how to make an id for each unique path for database or filesystem?

Comment: If the combintation of parts in your url is already unique, then you don't need to create a key, because you can simply use the url as is as the key. On a side note, consider using memcached or another key/value store instead of a flat file or the database for the caching.

Comment: in addition to the hash answer don't forget the obvious that JSON responses from an API can leverage HTTP caching like eTags or whatnot and you should leverage that too.  In other words traditional caching that works with "static" content could work still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a hash function to make a hash of the URL and use that as the cache ID. I do this on some of my projects for similar reasons.

`sha1($url);`

Which hashing function you use is up to you. [PHP hashes.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

Comment: hmm.. i tried this before, with md5, it wasnt working.. but its working now.. im guessing its because of timestamp, which generates different id's for the url., i need to convert timestamp to date.

Comment: Well, the reason it's shorter is because it's just 32bit as opposed to `md5` which is 128bit. You'd be more likely to get collisions with `crc32`. Probably won't be a problem, but I would go with `md5`.

Answer (score 2):

it php you have use the **[md5](https://www.php.net/md5)** method to generate the unique id,

```
$url = '/daily/12-02-20/yes/5/london.json';
$id = md5($url);
```

and now use this **$id** as id for that url..